Is the Oath Formula "By the Life of Pharaoh" Attested Anywhere outside of Biblical Literature?
In Genesis 42:15-16, Joseph swears "by the life of Pharaoh." I have searched unsuccessfully for the occurrence of this oath formula elsewhere in the literature of the Ancient Near East. Can anyone provide other instances of this phrase?

Nice Egyptology question!
For this you want Temple oaths in Ptolemaic Egypt : a study at the crossroads of law, ethics and religion (V Massa 2018)
I've pasted some relevant parts.
There's a problem with when to think Joseph is set - but this formula remained in use for an extremely long period: ~2500BC to ~30BC. It would be nice if one of these examples matches up neatly with when the OP places the composition of Genesis 42:15, but probably it's a case of arguing there are older examples and newer examples and we only need them to be familiar enough to the Genesis author and/or his audience for it to call to mind the Egyptian practice of deifying their ruler (e.g. as alien/distasteful).

ꜥnḫ
Verb and use: “As lives …”
Context of use: in juridical and non- juridical oaths
Period of use: Old Kingdom – Ptolemaic Period
ꜥnḫ(n=j) njswt /… “As the king / NN lives (for me)”54 [OK – NK]
n ḫ prꜥꜣ - “As Pharaoh lives” [NK – Ptol. Per.]

wꜣḥ
Verb and use: “As endures …”
Context of use: in juridical oaths
Period of use: New Kingdom – Late Period
wꜣḥ pꜣnjswt /… “As the king / NN endures” [NK]
wꜣḥ pꜣḥḳꜣ “As the Ruler endures” [NK]
wꜣḥ kꜣ… “As the Ka (of) NN endures” [NK; Late Per.]
wꜣḥh Imn ꜥnḫ Prꜥꜣ -
“As Amun endures, as Pharaoh lives” [3rd IP – Late Per.]

The oldest, and longest-lasting, invocation formula of the oath runs as follows: “As the king NN or god NN lives … (follows the text of the oath)”. The king is usually invoked by his name or only with the term njswt‘king’ (Old, Middle and New Kingdom); ḥḳꜣ
‘ruler’ (New  Kingdom) or prꜥꜣ‘pharaoh’ (from the New Kingdom onwards).55

In a Deir el-Medina ostracon, a village workman accuses a colleague of stealing three chisels belonging to Pharaoh. Two other workmen, who are said to have been witnesses to this deed, are brought into court and asked to testify. Before giving their statement they swear to tell the truth with the following words:
Ex. 17 m-bꜣḥ tꜣḳnb.t ḏdt.n=sn ꜥnḫn nb wꜣḥImn wꜣḥpꜣḥḳꜣpꜣy nty bin pꜣy=f bꜣw r mt Pr-ꜥꜣḏd.n=n m mꜣꜥ.t Pr-ꜥꜣbn ḏd=n ꜥḏꜣmtw=nḏd ꜥḏꜣiw=n ḥwi m sḫt  šd.tw nꜣẖꜣ.w m nꜣ(y)=snpr.w didi r Pr-ꜥꜣ
Oath of the Lord that they said before the court: “As Amun endures, as the Ruler endures, the one whose manifestation is worse than death, Pharaoh! We will say the truth (of) Pharaoh, we will not say falsehood; if we say falsehood, we will be beaten with  blows and the chisels will be taken from their (understand ‘our’) houses, (and) given to Pharaoh”. (deposition follows).

As remarked by Donker van Heel, the invocation formula type a may derive from the following Hieratic formula that was firstly attested in a juridical text of the 22nd Berlin P 3048, see ex. 31 below):
ꜥḫImn ꜥnḫPrꜥꜣꜥnḫḥ ṯ tpj n[Imn] dj n=f Imn pꜣḳ
“As Amun lives, as Pharaoh lives, as the first god’s servant of Amun lives! May Amun give him victory!”.
On the other hand, the invocation formula type b type a and the older, well- ꜥnḫn nb‘oath of the Lord’, i.e. wꜣḥ Imn wꜣḥ pꜣḥḳꜣ “As Amun endures, as the Ruler endures!”.
Invocation formula are sometimes abbreviated to a mere :
ꜥnḫ/wꜣḥImn ꜥnḫPrꜥꜣ   - -   “As Amun lives/endures, as the Pharaoh lives!"

